# Firebase LogEvents as doubles in a webview

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-analytics

Logging doubles to firebase analytics in a webview as recommended in the firebase [reference/example code on github](https://github.com/firebase/analytics-webview) will result in values ending up in different value fields depending on the value. The reason is that javascript has a Number type and decimals don't show when a value is an integer (i.e. 5.00 is represented as 5 while 5.01 is represented as 5.01). When parameters are logged with logEvent() in the webview, the  [AnalyticsWebInterface.java](https://github.com/firebase/analytics-webview/blob/ce453095e26b506665a45a8d4968cd258462945f/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/analytics/webview/AnalyticsWebInterface.java#L76) test whether the parameter value is a String, Integer or Double and store the value in the corresponding field (stringValue, intValue or floatValue). Hence, if you log the price of a product as a parameter, it will end up as intValue if the price is 5.00 and floatValue if the price is 5.01. This will really complicate analysis of that data.

```java
Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

   if (value instanceof String) {
       result.putString(key, (String) value);
   } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
       result.putInt(key, (Integer) value)      
   } else if (value instanceof Double) {
       result.putDouble(key, (Double) value);
   } else {
       Log.w(TAG, "Value for key " + key + " not one of [String, Integer, Double]");
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of solving it is to try to cast the value (if it is a String or Integer) and log it to multiple columns. Example:

```java
if (value instanceof String) {
            try{
                result.putString(key, (String) value);
                result.putDouble(key, Double.parseDouble((String) value));
                result.putInt(key, Integer.parseInt((String) value));
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            try{
                result.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
                result.putDouble(key, Double.valueOf((Integer) value));
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        if (value instanceof Double){
            result.putDouble(key, (Double) value);
        }
```